# Building page urls in php application

Tags: php, routes

I'm running my own extremely light MVC framework (without Router class).
To know what controller and action to run I'm using library or regexps applied to `REQUEST_URI`. Something like...

```
$regexps = array(
    '/admin/categories/' => array(
        'controller' => 'AdminCategories', 
        'action'     => 'index'
    ),
    '/admin/categories/add/' => array(
        'controller' => 'AdminCategories',
        'action'     => 'add'
    ),
);
```

Everything works fine, BUT...

**What is the best practice to BUILD urls?**

```
BuildUrl('Controller', 'action', array('var1' => 'val1', 'var2' => 'val2'));
```

**What is the best practice to modify current url (for, example I have table with 10 different filtering options)?**

```
ModCurrentUrl(array(...));
```

How do you solve this problem in your applications?

PS: I'm not using conroller's action parameters, all parameters are taken from $_GET.

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: solves only part of your question and am too busy to write something about, so it's only a comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Best practice ( as i see it ) would be to have a library called `Routing` ( basicly a class ) with static methods . You can then use `Routing::buildUrl(...)` , and fill it with all uri related methods you'll use ( like modCurrentUrl ... )

Comment: thank you for your comment! Creating static method is pretty clear for me, but I see problem in another... For example, you have url `/admin/categories/view/{{id}}/?filter1=a&filter2=b`; this url is routed to `AdminCategories` controller with `view` action. Now I'd like to create such url, using `Routing::buildUrl(...)`. I'm passing `array('id' => 123, 'filter1' => a, 'filter2' => b)` to `buildUrl` and I'm facing the problem with id parameter because it is in path, but not in QUERY_STRING. We can have many of such urls, so I should create separated method for each?

Comment: that's a design problem , you need to rethink buildUrl() method , to accept `controller , action , pathArray , queryArray` parameters , do you see where i'm getting with pathArray and queryArray parameters ?

Comment: well basicly you're passing controller and action strings in separate variables , so you're uri will look like /controller/action . then you get the third parameter pathArray witch holds for example ('1'=>'44','path1'=>'param') , you add those to the final uri to look like a path so you're uri should look like /controller/action/1/44/path1/param , or aditionaly you can tell it to look only like controller/action/44/param , then you take the 4'th argument from witch you build the query string like you did before and add it to the final uri.

Answer (score 0):

Here is couple good links for you:
http://robap.github.com/php-router/
http://code.google.com/p/routemap/
And i don't see any signs of subdirectories in your example. In big projects it could be fine.
Firstly request get to the router class' method, from there you get some actual data about the route. Secondly you put this data to a dispatcher which is starting your application.

Comment: Nice link, but I'm talking about another action. Building and modifying urls, not routing.

Comment: I'm talking about same thing :) Check out solutions from there, the code is quite simple. In two words you just need to mark somehow dynamic elements of the route, like 'controller/action/:id', then you'll be able to recognize them in your views (or wherever) to change dynamically. And there just build them dynamically like buildUrl( array( 'controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action', 'id' => $_GET[ 'id' ] ) )